# Recursive JS function misses every second loop

Tags: javascript

I have a function to take a format of

```
u1fsQExd1aZmnpL : {
    2FNdVdkaefaD6xQ : {
        fZ0zn6d51TgVqID : {
            05E1JSFYVHJlGVP : {}
        }
    }
}
```

And change it to

```
u1fsQExd1aZmnpL : {
    subfields : {
        2FNdVdkaefaD6xQ : {
            subfields : {
                fZ0zn6d51TgVqID : {
                    subfields : {
                        05E1JSFYVHJlGVP : {
                            subfields : {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it comes out as:

```
u1fsQExd1aZmnpL : {
    subfields : {
        2FNdVdkaefaD6xQ : {
            fZ0zn6d51TgVqID : {
                subfields : {
                    05E1JSFYVHJlGVP : {}
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: it misses the second `'subfields'` step.

It does this every second loop. ie: The next ID that is added to `05E1JSFYVHJlGVP` will be inside of it, without a `subfields` parent, but it will have a `subfields` child inside of it.

My method is:

```
        function get_into_subfields(form_structure) {
            for(var mainid in form_structure) {
                if(!form_structure[mainid].hasOwnProperty('subfields')) {
                    form_structure[mainid]['subfields'] = {};
                }
                for(var key in form_structure[mainid]) {
                    if(key != 'subfields') {
                        form_structure[mainid]['subfields'][key] = get_into_subfields(form_structure[mainid][key]);
                        delete(form_structure[mainid][key]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return form_structure;
        }
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

[Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9dfwroj/)

Comment: Could you boil this question down to the essentials? I have the impression this is a simple question that is really bloated. You essentially want a function that takes an object and "moves" its properties to another object stored as it's property `subfields`?

Comment: @JonSurrell yes, I want to take each step and insert a `subfields` key between them

Comment: Could you try to edit your question to make that clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simplify able, but I think your function is slightly complicated. The problem is that you do not want the *first* one to be a `subfields` object, but why not? That will make it easier and you will get the same result by simply adding `.subviews` to your result.

```js
var obj = {'u1fsQExd1aZmnpL' : {'2FNdVdkaefaD6xQ' : {'fZ0zn6d51TgVqID' : { '05E1JSFYVHJlGVP' : {}}}}}

function subfields(data){
  // Simply create a standard object that you can return
  var result = {subfields:{}};
  for(var key in data){
    // now recursively add it
    result.subfields[key] = subfields(data[key])
  }
  return result;
}

console.log('The full result', subfields(obj));
console.log('Ignore the initial subfield returned', subfields(obj).subfields);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(subfields(obj).subfields) + '</pre>')
```

This will leave you with an empty object at the end of the chain, which is assume is not a problem, although there is still a lot you can do to make sure this won't error out, the basics work.

Comment: This works, but the first one should not be a `subfields` value as I am building a question / form builder and the start of the tree (`u1fsQExd1aZmnpL`) is the main question, with sub questions under that

Comment: @Haring10 I know but you seem to be missing how easily you can get this out. Because your function is _consistent_ you can easily get the initial subfields result by doing `subfields(obj).subfields` to get the initial field as the first object. I have provided an update to my snippet to show exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Just get all keys and iterateover the properties. If the item is an object, iterate over the item.

```js
function go(r, o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        r[k] = { subfields: {} };
        typeof o[k] === 'object' && go(r[k].subfields, o[k]);
    });
}

var source = { 'u1fsQExd1aZmnpL': { '2FNdVdkaefaD6xQ': { 'fZ0zn6d51TgVqID': { '05E1JSFYVHJlGVP': {} } } } },
    target = {};

go(target, source);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(target, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I didn't know `document.write` could be used in SO snippets. It used to error out... Cool!